# Null pointer exception in array iteration

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am trying to figure out  why am i getting a null pointer exception

I have initialized it properly

And have tried and iterating through the code manually

I am all stuck with part......

```
private static final int PlacardHolderLength= 5 ;
private static final String  PlacardHolder[]= new String[5];
int PlacardHolderRemainingslots=PlacardHolder.length;

if((Placard_Details1[0]!=null) && (Placard_Details1[2]=="no"))
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<=PlacardHolder.length-1 ; i++)
    {
        // CHECK IF PRIMARY PLACARD IS PRESENT
        System.out.println("Value" +i);
        System.out.println("Valu2  " +PlacardHolder[0]);
        System.out.println("PLACARD HOLDER POSITION" +PlacardHolderPositions);

        if(PlacardHolder[i].equals(Placard_Details1[0]))
        { 
            //PLACARD eXISTING  DIALOG  BOX
            Flag_Placard_Existing=true;
            AlertMessageSamePlacard();
            getBannerData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with a window leak. Any exception or line number or snippet of code causing a problem?

Comment: Sorry I types a wrong title...

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception at

Comment: in the for loop..It iterate till 1  but  i dont see the last one

Comment: You might want to read this tutorial: http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `PlacardHolder` is an array of Objects (`Strings`), every entry is initialized with `null`. Before iterating through the array, you should assign each arrayelement an actual Object.

**EDIT**

Minor detail: if an entry in an array is null, you cannot call any methods from this element, so `PlacardHolder[i].equals(...)` generates the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply  But the loop iterates till the second element but not the last one

Answer (score 0):

You do *not* initialize the array properly, at least in the code shown, which is random fragments (you mix wtongly-static field declarations with a method body). Declaring an array still doesn't put elements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because of the line:

```
if(PlacardHolder[i].equals(Placard_Details1[0]))
```

`PlacardHolder[i]` may not have been initialized yet. In your if statement you check for `Placard_Details1[0]` and that would be sufficient if it was the object with the method being called.

```
if (Placard_Details1[0].equals(PlacardHolder[i]))
```

Assuming Placard_Details1[0] can compare against `null`, which it should be written to.